# Configure iptables to route to local network and to the internet

Tags: routes, iptables

I have a linux machine that acts as a router `R`, subnet `B` and a host `a`.
I want to create the following forwarding rules:

1. Route everything coming from B to some machine `a`.
2. From `a`, return traffic via NAT to everything that initiated on `B`.
3. Route every other traffic from `a` to the internet.

```
         Internet
            |
 ---       ---       ---
|   |<----|-/ |     |   |
| a |     | R |     | B |
|   |<----|---|---->|   |
 ---       ---       ---
```

iptables configuration on `R`:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth_to_a -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth_to_B -j SNAT --to IP_eth_B_R
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth_to_B -j DNAT --to IP_a
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth_to_a -o eth_to_B -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth_to_B -o eth_to_a -j ACCEPT
```

With this configuration, traffic from `B` to `a` works, but I fail to forward traffic from `a` to the internet (and back).

Answer (score 0):

Can you check which rule is hitting for the third case (forward traffic a to the Internet)? Check for packet drops as well. taking a trace would give some clue. 
I guess this rule might be hitting (iptables -A FORWARD -i eth_to_a -o eth_to_B )

I see one video where someone explains how to debug iptable rule related issue. Might be useful for you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uA9ik52N6AA